# Is autologon secure in the cloud

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, auto-login, autologon

I have a cloud windows server 2008 VPS.  I would like to have it autologin on startup.  Is doing so secure in a cloud environment?

More details:

The server doesn't store user details.  It just runs a script that fetches publicly available data through a windows program.  It needs to be secure enough so that nobody can log in through the internet without the password.  I'm not concerned about the datacenter being physically breached.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is fully secure; we are really talking how secure you want it to be. Auto-login on startup is not a secure practice, even in a cloud environment. But if you believe the security to get into your cloud based server is secure, then it is as secure as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As password for `autologon` is stored in Windows registry is secure as much as secure is access to the registry. Configuring `autologon` through `control userpasswords2` might be a bit more secure than direct registry edit - more as much as quality of hashing/salting of a password in this case.